# how to auto incremented a column of a table variable while inserting values in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @BusinessUnit AS Table( [id] varchar(10),sn int );
begin 

INSERT INTO @BusinessUnit([id])
SELECT name
FROM test 
WHERE course = 'Mca';
select * from @BusinessUnit;
end
```

how i assign auto increment value in sn field when the records are inserted in it.
I Need the following type of output:

```
id 'Deepak' sn  1 and id 'Rohan'  sn  2  like that
```

Answer (score 9):

Modify your table variable to use `IDENTITY` property for `sn` column:

```
DECLARE @BusinessUnit AS Table( [id] varchar(10), sn int IDENTITY (1,1) );
```

The rest of your code should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do

```
DECLARE @tblcustomers table  (id int, customername varchar(10));

insert into @tblcustomers values (1, 'aaa');
insert into @tblcustomers values (2, 'bbb');
insert into @tblcustomers values (3, 'ccc');
insert into @tblcustomers values (4, 'ddd');
insert into @tblcustomers values (5, 'eee');
insert into @tblcustomers values (6, 'fff');

Select * into #t from @tblcustomers
DECLARE @tblpurchase table  (Name VARCHAR(10), Sn int);
insert into @tblpurchase
SELECT Customername,ROW_NUMBER()over(ORDER BY ID  )As RN  FROM #t
select * from @tblpurchase
```

To get Identity column RowId